# Hitting time of Brownian Motion on a line

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Given a 3-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$, we know that it is transient. But how can we show that if it starts outside a straight line, it will remain outside forever with probability $1$ ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection of $B_t$ on a plane normal to the line is $2$-dimensional Brownian motion, which with probability $1$ will never hit the origin.

Comment: @Robert_Israel How can we rigorously prove that the orthogonal projection of a 3D Brownian motion is a 2D Brownian motion. Any hints?

Comment: Use coordinates so the orthogonal projection is $(x,y,z) \to (x,y)$.  The coordinates of an $n$-dimensional Wiener process are independent $1$-dimensional Wiener processes.
Depending on which definition you use, this is either a definition or a theorem.

Comment: This, plus invariance by rotation.